# How to find Qt5 packages, specific versions, on ubuntu?

Tags: qt, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

How do I search for packages containing specific versions of specific Qt5 modules for ubuntu? E.g. if my qml file contains:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.9
```

How do I find the package that provides QtQuick.Controls 2.9? Related question: For a given Qt5 package for ubuntu, how can I see what versions it contains?

Comment: That's not Ubuntu-specific: you need to manually find out the minimal Qt version needed and then hardcode it in the CMakeLists. Unfortunately i don't know a good overview relating the various QtQuick modules to Qt versions.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be no "standard" way of discovering which Qt versions are supported by which ubuntu packages.